# Changing random post publish time for repost

Tags: automatic-updates, wp-update-post

I have a lot of image posts. So, on weekends I don't work for that I want to re-post a random post. I made my own code. It schedules random post with its permalink too.

```
$time= strtotime("+10 min")                 // contains blog time matched
foreach($random_posts as $post) {

$repost = array(
      'ID'           => $post->ID,
      'post_date'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time),
      );
wp_update_post( $repost );
$time += 300;
}
```

How can I change a random post publish time for re-posting without changing post permalink, so that I won't pain google?

Comment: There is no `$posts` variable defined in your code. I suspect you will want to change `$posts->ID` to `$post->ID`.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson, sorry was a typo.

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: It was typo here, not in my original one.

Comment: can anyone please tell.

Comment: Are your permalinks date based? Is the problem that changing the post date also changes the link to the article because your permalinks are based on the date the article was published?

Comment: yes sir, you are correct. That's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Try changing your permalinks to some other structure. [This article](http://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/) from Otto will help you make the change and make the redirects for the old date based permalinks. After that, you should be able to change post dates safely.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson I tried, but not working. I am thinking to approach this problem by bringing any random post to the front page.